# Facing a situation where backslashes for escaping keep piling up

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

Here's the situation. I have a `form` like

```
<form id="myform">
     <input type="text" name="some_column_name">
     <input type="text" name="some_other_column_name">   
</form>
```

which is, in essence, for updating rows in a database. The database is "loaded" onto the page as `JSON` like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rows = <?php echo json_encode($allRows); ?>;
</script>
```

and when the user clicks an item on the page the form is populated with the corresponding info from the database (MySQL), which the user can then update and the updates will be submitted to the database.

The problem is with apostrophes and possibly other characters. Text that is entered to the database like

> Here's some text

becomes

> Here\'s some text

when it is loaded back into the `input`s on the page.

My procedures for adding and updating to the database are

```
/* Note: Have to break up prepare statement because https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12819 */
$addQuery = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO projs (compname,projname,imageurl,sumsmall,sumfull,results,caseid=" . $caseid . ",hide) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d)",
                            array($compname, $projname,$imageurl,$sumsmall,$sumfull,$results,$hide));        
$message .= $wpdb->query($addQuery) 
            ? 'Successfully added project to the database.'
            : 'Error occurred when trying to add project to database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
```

and

```
/* Note: Have to break up prepare statement because https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12819 */
$updateQuery = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE projs SET compname=%s,projname=%s,imageurl=%s,sumsmall=%s,sumfull=%s,results=%s,caseid=" . $caseid . ",hide=%d WHERE id=%d",
                              array($compname, $projname, $imageurl, $sumsmall, $sumfull, $results, $hide, $id));
$message .= $wpdb->query($updateQuery) !== false
            ? 'Successfully updated project.'
            : 'Error occurred when trying to update project in database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
break;
```

and I have a feeling that WordPress's `$wpdb->prepare` is screwing up stuff or that I'm misusing it or something.

Comment: Your PHP may have the `magic_quotes_gpc` option turned on, it adds slashes to inputs. Turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible issues here. You have either magic_quotes ON which will add \ to any character that may lead to an SQL injection such as ' and " or your prepare statement is adding it.
In this case, and with no much extra information available I am tempted to believe that your PREPARE statement is "sanitizing" the input and that's why you are seeing such values.

1. Check that magic quotes are not enabled.
2. Don't use the prepare statement.
3. Validate output so when it finds a value like \' coming out from the DB to the front-end it automatically strips the .

I hope this helped.